# How to view code documentation in Visual Studio without opening an external browser instance?

Tags: visual-studio

If I want to see the full documentation for a class or method in Visual Studio, I have to press `F1`. This opens an external browser window where I can look it up.

Now, I'd like to see the documentation within the IDE, in an integrated window, without having to mess around with a separate browser window. Additionally I'd like the documentation window to update as soon as I switch the cursor to another method/class/etc. This feature is fairly common in the Java IDEs.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior in Visual Studio?

Comment: Press Alt-F1 instead of just F1.

Comment: Take a look on Object Browser. This windows can be called by `Ctrl-Alt-J`. You can see well formatted comments for all type, that are reacheble from your solution. It is not a full documentation, but it is something. It also allows to navigate by reference to another tyes. By default VS doesn't offer you to find type in Object Browser directly from code, it is just able to search there. Resharper extension have such feature: right click on type\method\prop => navigate => object browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Help Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/microsoft-help-viewer-installation?view=vs-2017). See also [Video](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-visual-studio-2017-17798?l=ZMfaVID6D_7411787171).

If help viewer is already installed follow the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh580782.aspx) to enable it:

> When you install Visual Studio, you get the Help Viewer. To start reading help topics in the Help Viewer rather than on the MSDN download site, go to the **Help menu** in Visual Studio, select **Set Help Preference**, and then select **Launch in Help Viewer**. The off-line help topics for a given version of Visual Studio are available only after the final release of that version.

Beware, downloading help content for offline viewing can take a large amount of disk space!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to be on any method and while pressing on control, click the method. It will open up the method or class metadata file which gives out information about the available properties and values to be passed while giving out a summary of the method/class.

[Screen shot of IIdentityMessageService and what method it implements with a small desciption inside visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRLOr.jpg)